# android - problem in Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to prepare a layout which is same as the below attached image.

**My problems are indicated in image:**

1. I try to set-up buttons exactly same(width) as indicated as 1 in image
2. I try to set "save" and "Cancel" buttons at below with equal width.

[image]

I have tried it with the below XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget38"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:text="Event" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/editText1" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:hint="Tap to enter title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1">
    </EditText>

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/separator"         
        android:background="#ffffff"        
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical ="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/textView2" 
        android:text="From" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    </TextView>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2">
    </Button>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button2" 
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1">
    </Button>

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/separator1"        
        android:background="#ffffff"        
        android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical ="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/textView3" 
        android:text="To" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    </TextView>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button3" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3">
    </Button>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button4" 
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3">
    </Button>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:text="Save" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button6" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:text="Cancel" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you *question* is.

Comment: He wants his layout to match the layout in the image. Seems straight forward to me.

Comment: To the OP, it would be helpful if you could post an image of the layout resulting from your layout XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the *weight* of a button by using `android:layout_weight`

Here's an example of how to use it:
http://android.amberfog.com/?p=328

Comment: i got the idea for the Below "Save/Cancel" button, i have set the width as 0dp and then weight=1 to both the button.

Comment: Thanx for the great support, Now let me try again for the Upper bottons problem

Comment: Thanx a lot, for upper button, i have done with android:layout_width="wrap_content" for both buttons,and android:layout_weight="1" for first button and "0" for the button(Right-side) next to it.

Answer (score 1):

for buttons marked with 'image 1' you can set a fixed width like '16dip' i.e.

```
<Button 
        android:layout_width="16dip" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2">
    </Button>
```

for buttons below you can add into an LinearLayout horizontally oriented, with 0 width and a weight value

```
    <Button 
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:id="@+id/button4" 
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3">
        </Button>
```

Comment: +1, thanx for the support, i got the solution and its working fine, i am having "Save/Cancel" buttons at the bottom bar with equal length. Now, i am going to try for the above buttons with your solution. Please correct the above code: as button id is "button5" instead of "button4"

Comment: But I have tried to set fixed with to the upper bottons as "200dp" and "50dp" accordingly. Its looks fine and fitted very well in small screen. But When i test it in Large-screen, then the Right side area is coming as empty. So please help me.

Comment: For the upper button, i got the idea from the link provided by @Phonon, for that i have done with  android:layout_width="wrap_content" for both buttons,and   android:layout_weight="1" for first button and "0" for second button.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use horizontal linear layout. For the first issue you should set "weight" values for you buttons in .xml layout file

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you haven't the same with your xml code ?

You must use the `android:layout_weight`

if you want the button take the same place (cancel and valid button on your picture), you must put `android:layout_weight="1"` for both for example

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity's onCreate() method after setting the content view do the following.

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setWidth(findViewById(R.id.button5).getWidth());
findViewById(R.id.button2).setWidth(findViewById(R.id.button6).getWidth());
```

and let me know if this works.